# Unresponsiveness with Dell R410 server but cannot identify issue

Tags: dell

I'm experiencing an issue with a Dell R410 server whereby it randomly becomes unresponsive. Unresponsive = anything takes a long time to open, windows/applications freeze for a few seconds. This seems to be at random periods.

I've checked all the obvious things, task manager, OMSA, windows event logs, but I cannot see anything that could be causing this and, if I can't see it, I'm not sure where to look for the issue.

There's nothing abnormal in Task Manager, nothing in Windows Event log, OMSA reports all as normal, temperatures are good...

The configuration is:

2x X5675 CPU's
128GB RAM (8x16GB modules)
H700 RAID1 (2x2TB SATA)

BIOS and drivers are all up to date.

I'm a bit stuck as to where to look, if there were any indications,. it wold be much easier to resolve!

Thanks.

Comment: Very wild guess would be to check for SMART status of your drives, and running some RAM bench. Beware that with most RAID configuration, you won't have visibility over SMART counters for your disks/might want to take out disks and check for errors from a third-party station. Unless your DRAC has anything more interesting to say?

Comment: Agree with @SYN sounds like a hard disk issue. if you are running server 2016 or newer, look in task manager under the performance tab and see if the disk is near 100%.

Comment: Hi, tried looking at disk performance, it doesn't go anywhere near that nor shows any indication of being a problem. Haven't tried looking at the SMART details, but as they're new drives I doubt it's that (possible, of course, that one is faulty from new), but unlikely.